Measurability of $\int_\Omega \varphi(x)u(t,x) \mathrm{d}x$ for $\varphi \in L^1(\Omega)$ and $u$ in a Bochner space
I have a function $u \in L^\infty((0,\infty), L^\infty(\Omega))$ where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain. Take $\varphi \in L^1(\Omega)$ and consider
$$f(t) := \int_\Omega \varphi(x)u(t,x) \mathrm{d}x.$$
Does it follow that $f$ is measurable? How can I show this?
I think the difficulty is that we have $L^\infty$ in time over the unbounded interval $(0,\infty)$, so no embedding into $L^p$ is possible.

They seem to be measurable when both $u$ and $\phi$ are indicators?

Yes, $f$ is measurable: if $g\in V$ and $u\in L^\infty( (0,\infty), V^*)$ then $t \mapsto g(u(t)) \in L^1((0,\infty))$.
